# I registered Norwegian Autopass / EPCplc on a Swedish rental car a day late. Will the bill go to me or to the rental car company?

Tags: norway, tolls

I was driving a Swedish rental car in Norway on 1 August when I realised I was driving past an automatic toll collection point.  I couldn't reach the internet the same day, but the next morning on 2 August I registered with Norwegian Autopass / EPCplc and added the Swedish rental car for period 29 July to 13 August.  The Autopass website did not complain when I tried to register the rental car period back-dated, and the confirmation e-mail said it may be a couple of months before they send me a bill.  Does it matter that I registered at 2 August when I passed the toll at 1 August, considering I indicated I rented the car from 29 July?  Will the bill go to me or to the rental car company?  I'm worried that the rental car company may add a hefty administration fee on top of the modest toll road fee.

Comment: One would guess the bills from before you registered would go to the rental car company.

Comment: Your instinct is probably right. If I were you, I'd try calling the Norwegian Autopass place (or have a Norwegian person call on your behalf) and explain that you want to pay for the previous day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have e-mailed `AP@vegvesen.no`, and I received a reply.  I was told that I have done everything right and that I will get all invoices to my own e-mail address or postal address.

**Update**: Six months later, I did indeed receive a bill by e-mail asking me to pay a few dozen NOKs.

Comment: I will accept this answer when/if I indeed receive this invoice directly and I know it to be correct.